# Making the bash prompt smaller

Tags: windows, git, bash, ps1

Currently my Windows Git Bash shell prompt looks like this: 
`UserName@ComputerName Path (Branch)`

When I `echo $PS1`, I get:
`\[\033]0;$MSYSTEM:\w\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\]\w$(__git_ps1)\[\033[0m\]\n$`

In my `.bashrc` file I tried to update this like so:

`PS1="\[\033[32m\]\w$(__git_ps1)\[\033[0m\]\n$"`

What happens is that I lose the `UserName@ComputerName` which is what was intended. However for some reason, the `$(__git_ps1)` also disappeared.

When I however do it like this: `PS1=${PS1:46}` it works as expected.

My plan was to add some additional changes (replace a fixed path with nothing) so the substring method is less then optimal.

What's going on?

**UPDATE:**
When I execute the `PS1="\[\033[33m\]\w$(__git_ps1)\[\033[0m\]\n$"` in the shell directly, it also works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that due to the double quotes, `$(__git_ps1)` expands when you define the prompt rather than when the prompt is later drawn.

It works in the shell directly because by defining it again, you cause `$(__git_ps1)` to be expanded again for the directory you're in. If you change branch, you'll see that it's stuck.

The solution is to use single quotes so that `$(__git_ps1)` becomes a literal value in the prompt, to be evaluated later:

```
PS1='\[\033[33m\]\w$(__git_ps1)\[\033[0m\]\n$ '
```

Comment: Yaye it works. Why is it required to add an additional space at the end and a `\n` at the front to make it behave **exactly** the same while these were not present with the initial `echo $PS1`?

Comment: `echo "$PS1"`, quoted, means "Write out the value of `$PS1`". `echo $PS1`, unquoted, means "ruin all the whitespace and trash special characters". It's very counter-intuitive, I know. You can use `printf "PS1=%q\n" "$PS1"` to print out `$PS1` in a way that you can reuse as input.